# Iterate through list and show message when empty jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, each

I want to display a message when the `<section>` is “empty”. Inside the `<section>`, I can have an unknown number of `<ul>` and inside it an unknown number of `<li>`. When I click on “x” button it removes that `<li>`. Here’s the HTML:

```
<section>
  <ul>
    <li class="row  row--half-padding-top-bottom">
      <span>October 2013</span>
    </li>

    <li class="notification  notification--new">
      <span>
        <span>Franck Ribery</span>
        <span>Bayern Munich</span>
      </span>
      <span class="accept-ignore-container">
        <button class="js-animate-onclick--parent" title="Accept">Accept</button>
        <button class="js-connect-invite--ignore">&times;</button>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li class="notification  notification--new">
      <span>
        <span>Arjen Robben</span>
        <span>Bayern Munich</span>
      </span>
      <span class="accept-ignore-container">
        <button class="js-animate-onclick--parent" title="Accept">Accept</button>
        <button class="js-connect-invite--ignore">&times;</button>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li class="row  row--half-padding-top-bottom">
      <span>September 2013</span>
    </li>

    <li class="notification  notification--new">
      <span>
        <span>Franck Ribery</span>
        <span>Bayern Munich</span>
      </span>
      <span class="accept-ignore-container">
        <button class="js-animate-onclick--parent" title="Accept">Accept</button>
        <button class="js-connect-invite--ignore">&times;</button>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

I want to ignore the `<li>` element that shows the date (hence the “empty”, because it’s not really empty). To do that, I check if the `<li>` has a class `.notification`. If it has, increase the counter. I do that upon clicking the “x” button that has a class `.js-connect-invite--ignore`:

```
var counter;
$('.js-connect-invite--ignore').on('click touchstart', function() {
  var ul = $(this).closest('section').children();

  $(ul).each(function() {
    var li = $(this).children();
    counter = 0;

    $(li).each(function() {
      if ($(this).is('.notification')) {
        console.log('yes');
        counter ++;
      }
    })
  })
  console.log(counter);
})
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CCECK/

However, it’s not working properly as the logic is wrong. Do I need to add two counters?

How can upon clicking “x” check all the other elements and if that is the last `<li class="notification">` display an alert? Thanks!

Comment: alert on the last li within the section or under the specific date?

Comment: alert when the last `<li>` within the `<section>` is removed (ignore the specific date `<li>`)

Comment: @Alex Offtopic - where is Mario Mandžukić ? :D

Comment: @Vucko haha, he’s on the bench. Lewandowsk is on! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you reset the counter within **each** `ul`, so you always end up with the number of `li` elements of the last `ul`, which is 1. So if you reset the counter before iterating all the `ul` elements and also remove the `.notification` element on clicking the button then you can figure out when only one has been left.
You can try the following,

http://jsfiddle.net/Gd2kS/

**js**

```
var counter;
$('.js-connect-invite--ignore').on('click touchstart', function() {
  var ul = $(this).closest('section').children();

  counter = 0;

  $(ul).each(function() {
    var li = $(this).children();

    $(li).each(function() {
      if ($(this).is('.notification')) {
        console.log('yes');
        counter ++;
      }
    });
  });
    console.log(counter);
    if(counter==1){
        alert("last one left!!");
    }else{
        $(this).parents('.notification').remove();
    }
})
```

**EDIT** *- response to comments (hiding element with class `.visuallyhidden` instead of removing element)*

```
var counter;
$('.js-connect-invite--ignore').on('click touchstart', function() {
  var ul = $(this).closest('section').children();

  counter = 0;

  $(ul).each(function() {
    var li = $(this).children();

    $(li).each(function() {
      if ($(this).is('.notification')
          &&  !$(this).is('.visuallyhidden')) {/*<- modify the condition*/
         console.log($(this));
          console.log('yes');
          counter ++;

      }
    });
  });
    console.log(counter);
    if(counter==1){
        alert("last one left!!");
    }else{
        /*modify the removal*/
        //$(this).parents('.notification').remove();
        $(this).parents('.notification').addClass("visuallyhidden");
    }
})
```

Comment: @Alex if you want to use class names instead of removing, you can modify the condition of `.notification` li elements and modify the removal part http://jsfiddle.net/Gd2kS/2/ . Also updating the answer with the relevant code.

Comment: @Alex great, i'll post the code from the fiddle in the answer, to assist other visitors as well, if you want to modify it with your own version please do so, thanks.